# Prolog Between two set times

Tags: prolog

LONG STORY SHORT

I have a file called timetable.pl that has a pradicate (r,s,t)- `r` is the name of the train, `s` is the list of stations it stops at and `t` is a list of given times for the them stops.

THE file `timetable.pl` defines a predicate `nextTime` so that next `time(t1,t2)` holds if `t2` is five minutes after `t1`.

I have to define a predicate si after `t1`, `t2` holds if `t2` is after and before midnight..

I just need some guidance here.

Comment: Can you show a sample of your `timetable.pl` the file? And could you give an example of how you want your new predicate to behave? It's unclear from your description.

Comment: @mbratch thats the issue here, we were never given one.. this is exactly what it says:

an example of timetable.pl is:

trains(kx12000,[london,peterborough,york,newcastle,edinburgh], ['12':'00','12':'45','13':'55', '14':'50:, '16:'20'])

Comment: The sentence I'm having trouble deciphering is, *I have to define a predicate si after t1, t2 holds if t2 is after and before midnight.*. Is that exactly how the problem is stated?

Comment: @mbratch sorry its late here in the UK and ive been up all day!

It reads exactly as this "define a predicate so that after(t1,t2) holds if t2 is anytime after t1 but before midnight

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you want to think about a reasonable way to represent times of day.

Prolog lets you use your own functors to structure data as you wish. So you can have `name(fred)` and process or manipulate this piece of information with code that you write. Prolog doesn't affix any special meaning to it other than knowing it's a functor `name` and one argument, an atom, `fred`.

This also works with infix functors. So you can represent a time of day as, `HH:MM`. For example,

```
Time = 12:42.
```

Here, the user-defined functor is `:` and it has two integer arguments: `12` and `42`. This could also be written, `':'(12,42)`.

If I have a time `Time` that uses this representation, I can separate out the hours and minutes by unifying it with the functor form:

```
| ?- Time = 12:42, Time = Hours:Minutes.

Hours = 12
Minutes = 42
Time = 12:42

yes
| ?-
```

If you have to times, `T1` and `T2`, and they use this representation, you can compare these two times just by comparing their component hours and minutes as integer values. Assuming a 24-hour format, if `Time1 = H1:M1` and `Time2 = H2:M2`, then `Time1` is less than `Time2` if `H1 < H2`, or if `H1 = H2` and `M1 < M2`.

This works well for 24-hour time. If you want 12-hour time with an AM/PM designator, you can do it a number of ways, such as, `tod(HH:MM, AMPM)` (example: `tod(12:42, am)`), or `[HH:MM, AMPM]` (example: `[12:42, pm]`). When having to compare and manipulate times, the 24-hour format is easier. :)

Comment: this was VERY helpful, I tried.. After(t1,t2) but im getting an error -- undefined procedure

Comment: @CeriWestcott - you'll need to show your code, if you don't mind. Also, note that predicates *must* start with a lower case letter, `after` not `After`. And variables *must* start with an upper case letter `T1` not `t1`.